# “Is there anything more you would like to say?”

Tags: expressions, questions

Will I be using proper grammar if I ask someone, “Is there anything more you would like to say?” I need to know if I’m able to use the word more instead of the word else.

Answer (score 1):

This is grammatically correct and natural.  The meaning is almost identical, with a slight nuance of "else" meaning "something different" and "more" meaning "something additional"

But most people would use more/else interchangeably.